# Upload to Ooyala with Fine Uploader

Tags: fine-uploader, ooyala

We would like to see if Fine Uploader can be integrated with Ooyala. I am sure it can be done, but would rather not re-invent the wheel here.

Here is the Ooyala API for reference:
http://support.ooyala.com/developers/documentation/api/assets.html

Has anyone seen this integration done before? Any sample projects?

Comment: I added a suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported by Fine Uploader's features. Maybe in the future [if there is interest in this feature.](https://github.com/widen/fine-uploader/issues/new).

**Update:**
One idea is have a temporary upload server that Fine Uploader sends files to. Once file(s) are received, they are sent to Ooyala using one of their [SDKs](http://support.ooyala.com/developers/resources#sdks).